# why is modernizr is detecting generatedcontent in ie7?

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

i thought that ie7 does not support the css psudo elements :before and :after?
so why is modernizr detecting that generatedcontent == true?

Am i missing something?

Comment: This demo returns `false` for me in IE7 on Win XP: http://cdpn.io/kdvbz - I see this issue was raised a while ago though, so maybe a false positive has been fixed since then?